# Removing urlEncodingAttributes values breaks page (hybris)

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I copied powertoolsinitialdata and made it my store after changing names.

Now I can go to localhost my site and see powertools products.

In `site.impex` , there is a part:

```
# CMS Site
INSERT_UPDATE CMSSite;uid[unique=true];theme(code);channel(code);stores(uid);contentCatalogs(id);defaultCatalog(id);defaultLanguage(isoCode);urlPatterns;active;previewURL;startingPage(uid,$contentCV);urlEncodingAttributes;defaultPromotionGroup(Identifier)[default=mysitePromoGrp]
;$siteUid;lambda;B2B;$storeUid;$contentCatalog;$productCatalog;$defaultLanguage;(?s).*;true;$storefrontContextRoot/?site=$siteUid;homepage;storefront,language,currency;
```

This is default from powertools.

So I have to go to

https://localhost:9002/mysite/en/USD/

instead of the only localhost.

For it, I deleted those parameters.

and made `site.impex` like this

```
# CMS Site
INSERT_UPDATE CMSSite;uid[unique=true];theme(code);channel(code);stores(uid);contentCatalogs(id);defaultCatalog(id);defaultLanguage(isoCode);urlPatterns;active;previewURL;startingPage(uid,$contentCV);urlEncodingAttributes;defaultPromotionGroup(Identifier)[default=mysitePromoGrp]
;$siteUid;lambda;B2B;$storeUid;$contentCatalog;$productCatalog;$defaultLanguage;(?s).*;true;$storefrontContextRoot/?site=$siteUid;homepage;;;
```

I deleted only last 3 parameters

```
storefront,language,currency;
```

which are urlencodinggatrributes.

Then I again made ant initialize (also I tried importing from console).

After clearing cache or going incognito, I see such a bottom of powertools

https://pasteboard.co/HqKOciV.png

Why is that? Why is it not proper? I want to remove those parameters. Should I remove from also somewhere else?

I don't want to do via WCMS or adding another Impex like

```
 INSERT_UPDATE CMSSite;uid[unique=true];urlEncodingAttributes
```

I could not find any solution for that wish. I searched a lot but no solutiions for this.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove these **urlEncodingAttributes** in either way from impex/hmc/backoffice and just do server up once. It will fix your issue. If you initialize, then again those impexes will be imported. You should do this after initialization.

Can you check from where this image is getting appended?